# How to edit the int value in the data table?

Tags: javascript, datatable, webix

The Webix library provides 10 predefined editors: text, inline-text, password; checkbox, inline-checkbox; select, combo, richselect; multiselect (Webix Pro edition only); date; color; popup.

But I need to edit int value in the Webix Datatable component. How can I do that?

Comment: You have to provide some example...

Comment: Which functionality you want to have in "number" editor? Default "text" editor can be used for both numeric and text values.

Comment: I need to have only numbers in the field, no text, and "text" editor allows me to write instead of (1) also text (1text)